# Authenticate to BlobServiceClient using ClientSecretCredential in a native app

Tags: azure-storage, azure-authentication

I am trying to authenticate to azure blob storage in a native .net app.  The following code yields a 403. I don't see any auth flow triggered (eg no consent or TFA prompt), but maybe that shouldn't be expected.  The client registration is configured as a native app with user_impersonation scope.  I'm wondering what steps I should take to troubleshoot.

```
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantid, appid, clientSecret);                                
client = new BlobServiceClient(accountUri, credential);

// Make a service request to verify we've successfully authenticated
var foo= await client.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

Response:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:73e54cff-401e-004d-7211-685a00000000
Time:2020-08-01T14:37:01.2280787Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Headers:
x-ms-request-id: 73e54cff-401e-004d-7211-685a00000000
x-ms-client-request-id: a9a34270-db76-424b-ac33-750b2cdb2ffb
x-ms-version: 2019-12-12
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2020 14:37:00 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Content-Length: 279
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to client  credential flow to access Azure storage, we need to assign Azure RABC role (Storage Blob Data Contributor) to the Azure AD application. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal)

For example

1. [Register Azure AD application via Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).
2. [Create a client secret for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-credentials-to-your-web-application)
3. Azure RABC role (Storage Blob Data Contributor) to the Azure AD application.
   [image]
4. Code

```
var clientId = "42e0d***2d988c4";
            var secret = "Gbx2***fQpIjoae:";
            var tenant = "e4c9ab4***2a757fb";

            ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, clientId, secret);
            string accountName = "jimtestdiag924";

            string url = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName);
            var client = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), credential);

            var foo = await client.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is adding the RBAC role also required if I use delegated permissions and InteractiveBrowserCredential? It turns out I needed tenant admin approval on the appid, and I'm waiting on that to percolate.  I'm looking to author a general tool for our tenant and can't add the role to every storage account that might use it.

Comment: @RobertSim If you  use client credential flow, you can assign the role at subscription level, then you can manage all storage blob service in the subscription.

Comment: @RobertSim Besides, if you use the delegated permissions, you also need  to assign the role to user.

Comment: Thanks, assigning the role to the user is probably fine.  I need azCopy-like functionality so the user should have rights on the blob.  Thanks for your help!